# How do you get a City Clerk to open/release the Plain Text Records of Public Meetings?

Tags: government, local-government

a) How do you get Boston City Clerk to open/release the Plain Text Stenograph Record of Public Meetings of Boston City Council for hard of hearing, deaf, ESL English as a Second Language folks?... Article 2.3 of the City Stenography Contract provides the Plain Text is Public Record. Only the .sgstn StenoGraph StenoNote raw file is released not the Additional File needed for Plain Text compiled/used in the Council Chamber during Public Meetings. See also

http://citystenographboston.blogspot.com/

b) How do you get new technologies and software to problematical government offices that make an easier to use stenographic record of Public Meetings of Boston City Council for hard of hearing, deaf, ESL English as a Second Language folks?...

c) How do you get the release of the Full Text of WGBH Captioning Services Captions from the Webcast/Cablecast of Public Meetings of Boston City Council?...

Muckrock.com failed, the Public Records Division of the Secretary of the Commonwealth of Massachusetts failed and the Open Government Division of the Massachusetts Attorney General failed.

Comment: You should amend this to be more general. Stack Exchange questions are supposed to be helpful for more than just one user.

Comment: You ask. If that doesn't work, you have a lawyer ask.

Comment: have you tried to call them?

Comment: >"You should amend this to be more general. Stack Exchange questions are supposed to be helpful for more than just one user." Our communities include, hard of hearing, tinnitis ringing in the ears, deaf, ESL English as a Second Language folks, concussion recovery, stroke recovery folks, folks with cognitive difficulty, dyslexic, ADD attention deficit, elderly, folks with difficulty to tolerate hard aggravating public seats of the Council Chamber, folks in city neighborhoods far afield of City Hall, Hyde Park folks, Mattapan folks, Orient Heights folks.

Comment: >"You ask." Denial responses. >"If that doesn't work, you have a lawyer ask." Available attorneys at State Secretary & State Attorney General tried. Any affordable private attorneys with a subspecialty in this area of administrative law, municipal law, open government? >"have you tried to call them?" yep, more denial.

Comment: @PointlessSpike they don't. There's plenty of questions on Stack Overflow itself that are helpful only for the user who asks them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

'"Too localized" should be used for very tiny geographic regions or vanishingly small periods of time. It is used when a question cannot possibly be answered because nobody participating in the site is likely to know the answer, and even if it were answered, nobody else would care.'

Makes it sound like it's only valid if no-one else will care.

Answer (score 2):

In general, requests for public records should be made via a [Freedom of Information Act](http://www.foia.gov/) request, aka FOIA.

Technically, FOIA is a federal law, but Massachusetts has [this](http://www.nfoic.org/massachusetts-sample-foia-request) equivalent. [More here](http://www.sec.state.ma.us/pre/prereq/reqidx.htm)

Typically, a FOIA request will come with a cost associated with any necessary procurement by the government agency involved. Translation between formats may also end up being your responsibility.

---

If the issue is accessability, look at the [Americans With Disabilities Act of 1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) which often requires governments to make records accessible to those with disabilities. NOte again, however, costs associated with the translation may have to be borne by the party requesting it.

Massachusetts has law in this regard here: http://www.sec.state.ma.us/pre/prepdf/guide.pdf

Specifically,

> 950 CMR 32.00 shall be construed to ensure the public prompt access to all
>   public records in the custody of state governmental entities and in the custody
>   of governmental entities of political sub-divisions of the Commonwealth, and
>   to ensure that disputes regarding access to particular records are resolved
>   expeditiously and fairly. 950 CMR 32.00 shall not limit the availability of
>   other remedies provided by law

Comment: Public Records Division of the Secretary of the Commonwealth of Massachusetts tried. The Determination Ordered release of the unreadable raw file not the additional file needed for Plain Text that Article 2.3 Performance of the City Stenography Contract provides for on Contract page number 3, document page 4 at https://muckrock.s3.amazonaws.com/foia_files/stenographer_contract_fy15.pdf

Comment: Do you care about the answer or are you just trying to make a point?

Comment: @theszak If you don't know how to use the file they sent you, maybe http://superuser.com/ is a better place to ask?

Comment: @theszak - We're an internet site. There's nothing *we* can do to fix things except give you information.  If that information doesn't help, there's nothing more we can do.  Try contacting a local lawyer or local news media.  The former can tell you whether you did everything right and/or there's more you can do, and the latter can make a big deal about it if they're really being obstructionist.

Comment: @SamIam - Not much better [over there](http://superuser.com/questions/862389/how-do-you-convert-sgstn-stenograph-stenonote-files-to-plain-text).

Comment: >"Do you care about the answer" yep, care about getting more information. >"or are you just trying to make a point?" wouldn't rule that out! And there're other things besides asking, getting more information about challenging predicaments at City Hall.

Comment: >"...a better place to ask?" Thank you! A hint, tip, pointer that could get converting it further along.

Comment: >"...Try contacting a local lawyer" Ah if only there were an affordable attorney with a subspecialty in administrative law, municipal law, open government! >"or local news media. The former can tell you whether you did everything right and/or there's more you can do, and the latter can make a big deal about it if they're really being obstructionist." A couple journalists have been in touch in addition to http://muckrock.com

Comment: If you are trying to make a point, this is explicitly not what we do here.

Comment: Please suggest a useful alternative to politics.stackexchange.com or a useful alternative to stackexchange.com

Comment: Quora.  This isn't a place for making arguments, it is  aplace for getting information about how political systems work. Honestly, I don't care if you're right or wrong. Why do you care what I think about how Boston should work anyway?